# How to read docx with line breaks in website js?

Tags: javascript, docx

I am currently working on a web app for which I need to read text from a .docx-file in the front-end, using JavaScript. For the later usage of the text it's important to also read linebreaks in the text.
Currently I am working with docxtemplater's getFullText()-method, which is fine to read the text, but it does not give me the line breaks.

My current code lokes as follows:

```
function openDocx(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        var zip = new JSZip(reader.result);
        var doc = new window.docxtemplater().loadZip(zip);
        var text = doc.getFullText();
        console.log(text)
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(input.files[0]);
};
```

So for the text in a .docx, let's say

```
Hello World
How are you?
```

It would give me "Hello WorldHow are you?", but I would want "Hello World\nHow are you?".
Has anybody else had the same problem and found a solution or does anybody have an idea how to get the line breaks? If necessarry, I am also willing to go away from docxtemplater and use another library.

Thanks in advance

Robert

Comment: `getFullText` does not return newlines, there are a few issues regarding that on github like [Read Text including line-breaks and markup #193](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater/issues/193). The answers to that are, that this is intended. So you can't use `getFullText` for that.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. More I was wondering if there is any other library or method which does read the line breaks as well.